# Using sed for changing a line of a file containing a path

Tags: bash, sed

i have a light knowledge of the bash but i search a lot for it and always found my way to do what i want ... except this time ....

My goal is to make a "sed" in a loop so that my script enter a file and replace some lines with others.

for example

```
1 blabla
2 blabla
3 linetoreplace1
4 blabla
5 blabla
6 linetoreplace2
```

i must replace line 3 and 6 by something else

The number of each line to replace are stored in a variable :

```
cat lines
1
14
16
150
159
```

and the replacement texts (which are links) are stored in another variable :

```
cat pathlines
./home/newlink_toplace1
./home/newlink_toplace2
./home/newlink_toplace3
./home/newlink_toplace4
./home/newlink_toplace5
```

so in the end my script "myscript.sh" acting on "file.txt" looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

#the variables containing the number of the lines and the replacing text are already defined in the current directory

#lines.txt
#text.txt

for i in $(seq 1 15)
do

# i put the replacing texte from the list to a variable "reptext"

sed "${i}q;d" text.txt > reptext

#i put the line where we should do the replacement in "line"

sed "${i}q;d" lines.txt > line

# ...and finally the command to do the job  

sed -i "${line} s/^\text_to_replace/\'"$reptext"'/" file.txt

done
```

i received multiple error message including :

```
 > sed -i -e "${i} s /^\voila/\'"$reptext"'/" file.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command

> sed -i "${i}s/.*/'"$reptext"'/" file.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'

 > sed -i '${i}s/^\''/\'"$reptext"'/' file.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

 > sed -i "${i}s /^\voila/\'"$reptext"'/" file.txt 
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unterminated `s' command
```

and sometime no error but in the end no action from the script

```
> sed -i "${i}s/^\voila/\${reptext}/" file.txt
```

In the end i have tried different sytaxes , stored my variable in a different way , and tried different way to express my variable inside the sed instead of '"$repext"' :

```
`cat reptext`

echo "$reptext"

"'`("'$£**~##{{[|~|`reptext{~#[`|{[`\\^'"
```

rm privatepartofmycomputerandlethimsufferslowly

Can you help me

thanks a lot in advance

jan

Comment: wrt `My goal is to make a "sed" in a loop` - that is a bad goal, read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice. This sounds like a job for a small, simple awk script.

Comment: i'll check and report result asap, thank you :)

Comment: @EdMorton , this is a good article, and in the future i will work more with the embedded functionalities of the sed and the awk instead of using a loop, thank you very much for your information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed, paste and bash's [Process Substitution](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC35):

```
sed -f <(paste -d " " lines.txt pathlines.txt | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\1s|.*|\2|/') input.txt
```

With lines.txt:

```
2
6
12
33
50
```

Output:

```
1 blabla
./home/newlink_toplace1
3 linetoreplace1
4 blabla
5 blabla
./home/newlink_toplace2
```

Comment: Nice. Just curious about the expected output from OP :-)

Comment: i am testing in my case and i report asap :)

Comment: thanks for your answer @Cyrus but i have error :
'ed: file /dev/fd/63 line 1: unknown command: `
i have direclty copied your line  , and i don't find mistake in it :( what could it be ?

Comment: @FredrikPihl for your curiosity , i am creating another script in another language (strange_script). This programme will take some file in order to post-process them. In the end , my bash script will change the path in the strange_script according to the answer of the user.

So " which data you want to post treat ? " => answer => bash_script changes all the path in the strange_script => strange_script execute itself and now where to find the data :D

Comment: i was sure i did not make any typo ... i guess i was tired that moment, you are right, i wrote "ed" instead of "sed" ... feeling stupid but relieved in the same time. thanks a lot @Cyrus

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk with some other stuff

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {replacement[$1] = $2; next} 
    FNR in replacement {print replacement[FNR]; next} 
    {print}
' <(paste lines pathlines) filename.for.replacing
```

demo

```
$ awk '
>     NR == FNR {replacement[$1] = $2; next} 
>     FNR in replacement {print replacement[FNR]; next} 
>     {print}
> ' <(paste lines pathlines) <(seq 20)
./home/newlink_toplace1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
./home/newlink_toplace2
15
./home/newlink_toplace3
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: No error but only the seq 20 ( numbers from 1 to 20 ) display , no replacement :(